# Datepicker Bootstrap don't save

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I'm currently trying to use the gem datepicker which look absolutely amazing, but is not working. 
Actually, the popup with the table from the gem it's working, and the date is displayed in the text field but when I try to save, their is nothing in my sql table

My code :

tasks/_form (for new task) :

```
<div class="row-clearfix">
<%= form_for([@ranch, @ranch.tasks.build]) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: "New task", style: "width: 600px; border: solid 0.1px" %>



  <%= f.text_field :date, 'data-behaviour' => 'datepicker',style: "width: 100px; border: solid 0.1px"  %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('[data-behaviour~=datepicker]').datepicker({
    autoclose: true
  });
</script>

  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
</div>
```

&&

```
//= require jquery_ujs
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a strong params issue. In your controller, make sure you've specified :date in params.require(:ranch).permit(...)